# Activity using ViewPager, PagerAdapter and AsyncTask doesn't present the content

Tags: parsing, android-viewpager, dynamic-content

I'm trying to build an Activity with a layout similar to the new Android Market, mosaic style, that list information in each mosaic. When the user swipes left or right, they'll see more and more mosaics with information. The quantity of information is dynamic, because it is loaded from a XML file, with an AsyncTask.

I decided to use ViewPager/PagerAdapter to handle the views and control the paging. Each page will have a LinearLayout, similar as the picture in this link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4458251/mosaic.png

Each square in the mosaic is a RelativeLayout with an image and a textview.

**The problem I'm having is that the first view displayed is always blank and when I try to change the page, a force close error is showed. Also, when I debug, I found that `instantiateItem()` method in `PagesContentAdapter.java` was not entered at all**! What gives?.

Here's my activity (`MosaicMenuActivity.java`):

```
public class MosaicMenuActivity extends Activity {
public final String TAG = "NoniusDroidBaseApp";

// The title image (on top of the window)
private String TITLE_IMAGE = "title/title_MAIN";
// The background (normally you don't want to change it)
private String BACKAGROUND_IMAGE = "background";

// The content loader is used to load the application on another thread
// It makes sure that you can't interact with the application until the load
// is completed,
// but it will also blocks allows you to exit the application while it it
// loading.
// The interface will also never block
private PageContentLoader content_loader;

// The content adapter holds one application content array.
private PagesContentAdapter content_adapter;

// Actual system language
private String language;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Apply the main.xml as the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Apply the Nonius default theme
    getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.Theme);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Whenever the application resumes, the loader check if the Theme
    // changed (or the language was modified)
    // If it was modified, it loads the theme again
    if (ThemeManager.themeModified(language)) {
        loadTheme();
    }

    // Get the actual system language
    language = SetTopBoxDetails.getLanguage();

    // Build the content adapter
    this.content_adapter = new PagesContentAdapter(
            this.getApplicationContext(), language);

    // Applies the content adapter to the content ViewPager
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.scrollview_pages);
    myPager.setAdapter(content_adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    // Builds the module that will load the content from the xml
    this.content_loader = new PageContentLoader(this, content_adapter, language);
    // The content is read whenever the application resumes
    loadDynamicContent();
}


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown");
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/*
 * This function is used to load content that comes from outside of the
 * application.
 */
private void loadDynamicContent() {
    // The content loader makes sure that the user can't interact with the
    // application until the load is done.
    this.content_loader.execute();
}

/*
 * Loads the application theme.
 */
private void loadTheme() {
    // Get the context
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

    // Load the background
    RelativeLayout relativelayout_base = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_base);
    relativelayout_base.setBackgroundDrawable(ThemeManager.getImage(
            BACKAGROUND_IMAGE, context));
}
```

The AsyncTask is made by my `PageContentLoader.java`. I get all the data from the XML but it is not presented:

```
public class PageContentLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    public static final String TAG = "PageContentLoader";
    private static int SLEEPING_TIME = 2000;

    // The location of the XML file
    private static final String XML_PATH = "/data/nonius/menu/mosaic.xml";

    // XML node keys used to parse xml
    private static final String KEY_PAGE = "page";
    private static final String KEY_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "template";
    private static final String KEY_TILE = "tile";

    // The parent activity. Used to lauch UI items
    private MosaicMenuActivity activity;

    // The content storage
    private PagesContentAdapter content_adapter;

    // The dialog that locks the user interaction
    private LoaderDialog dialog;

    // The array of content (in this demo, Pages!)
    public ArrayList<Page> pages;

    private String language;

    public PageContentLoader(MosaicMenuActivity activity,
            PagesContentAdapter content_adapter, String language) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.pages = new ArrayList<Page>();
        this.dialog = new LoaderDialog(this.activity);
        this.content_adapter = content_adapter;
        this.language = language;
    }

    public boolean loadXml() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadXml");
        // Clean the pages array
        this.pages = new ArrayList<Page>();

        // Get the DOM element
        Document doc = XmlHelper.getDomElement(XML_PATH);
        // If the document is null
        if (doc == null) {
            // Return fail
            return false;
        }

        // Get all the nodes with tag KEY_PAGE
        NodeList page_nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PAGE);
        Log.d(TAG, "getElementsByTagName");

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int page_i = 0; page_i < page_nodelist.getLength(); page_i++) {
            Page page = new Page();

            Log.d(TAG, "Page " + page_i);
            // Get the element of the node list
            Element page_element = (Element) page_nodelist.item(page_i);

            String page_template = page_element.getAttribute(KEY_PAGE_TEMPLATE);
            page.setTemplate(page_template);

            NodeList tile_nodelist = page_element
                .getElementsByTagName(KEY_TILE);

            for (int tile_i = 0; tile_i < tile_nodelist.getLength(); tile_i++){
                // Create an empty tile
                Tile tile = new Tile();

                Element tile_element = (Element) tile_nodelist.item(tile_i);
                tile.importXmlElement(tile_element);

                page.addTile(tile);

                Log.d(TAG, tile.toString());
            }

            this.pages.add(page);
        }

        // Everything went ok
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setLoadMode(activity.getString(R.string.loading_message));
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Parse the xml file
        return this.loadXml();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        // If the loader succeeded
        if (success) {
            // Update the adapter
            content_adapter.updateContent(pages);

            // If the dialog is visible, hide it
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        // If the loader failed
        else {
            // Start the error dialog
            dialog.setErrorMode(activity
                .getString(R.string.loading_error_message));
        }
    }
}
```

The PagerAdapter is in my `PageContentAdapter.java`. After make some debug the construct method is called successfully, but the method where the page content is created (`instantiateItem()`) is never called:

```
public class PagesContentAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public static final String TAG = "PagesContentAdapter";
// The list context
private Context context;

// The content array
public ArrayList<Page> pages;

// The system language
private String language;

/**
 * Class constructor
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The context used to build the ouput views
 */
public PagesContentAdapter(Context context, String language) {
    this.context = context;
    // Create an empty pages array
    this.pages = new ArrayList<Page>();
    this.language = language;
}

/**
 * Update the Adapter pages array and notify the parent
 * that the data was modified
 * @param pages
 */
public void updateContent(ArrayList<Page> pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
    //this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pages.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);

}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View page_view, int position) {
    Page page = new Page();
    page = pages.get(position);

    LayoutInflater page_layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearlayout_page = (LinearLayout) page_layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_template_5icons_v1, null);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        linearlayout_page.addView(layoutTile(linearlayout_page, page, i));
    }

    ((ViewPager) page_view).addView(linearlayout_page, 0);

    return linearlayout_page;
}

public RelativeLayout layoutTile(LinearLayout linearlayout_page, Page page, int index) {
    RelativeLayout relativelayout_tile = null;

    switch(index) {
        case 0: relativelayout_tile = (RelativeLayout) linearlayout_page.findViewById(R.id.item_big_1);
        case 1: relativelayout_tile = (RelativeLayout) linearlayout_page.findViewById(R.id.item_small_1);
        case 2: relativelayout_tile = (RelativeLayout) linearlayout_page.findViewById(R.id.item_small_2);
        case 3: relativelayout_tile = (RelativeLayout) linearlayout_page.findViewById(R.id.item_small_3);
        case 4: relativelayout_tile = (RelativeLayout) linearlayout_page.findViewById(R.id.item_small_4);
    }

    // Inflate it in a layout xml
    LayoutInflater tile1_layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tile1_layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, relativelayout_tile);
    // Get the textview from the inflated layout
    TextView textview_tail = (TextView) relativelayout_tile.findViewById(R.id.textview_tile);
    Tile tile = page.getTiles().get(index);
    // Set its text
    textview_tail.setText(tile.getDescription());

    return relativelayout_tile;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks for taking the time to review this question!**